# How to post non-ascii chars in a HTML from and read it using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, utf-8, character-encoding

I have created a small HTML form and saved it as an `UTF-8`-encoded PHP-file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My form</title></head>
<body>
<h1>My form</h1>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="myfield" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I type `Öst` in the text field and post it, the swedish letter `Ö` is stripped so I only get `st` when I read it with `$_POST['name']`. I am using CodeIgniter PHP Framework, and if I read it with `$this->input->post('name');` I get the same result, only `st`.

Why do I get this problem? Do CodeIgniter strip my swedish letter or do I have some problem with the character encodings?

**UPDATE:** I have added a meta-tag `<meta charset="utf-8" \>` in the header and now it works.

Comment: What sanitation do you use on the PHP side?

Comment: @powtac: I use both `$_POST['name']` and `$this->input->post('name');` as I wrote in the question.

Comment: if you found a solution either mark the person that helped you, or post your own solution and mark it as an answer that is the SO way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you make sure that your HTML output is UTF-8 (proper header), you may use this function when outputing details in a form in order not to break the text:

```
form_prep()
```

Allows you to safely use HTML and characters such as quotes within form elements without breaking out of the form. Consider this example:

```
$string = 'Here is a string containing "quoted" text.';    
<input type="text" name="myform" value="$string" />
```

Details are [here in the User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

Answer (score 2):

Guess here is an answer tailored for Codeigniter:

http://www.haughin.com/2010/02/23/building-utf8-compatible-codeigniter-applications/

Basically, you'll have to create new form_helper.php file with modified form_open and form_prep functions. These modifications will allow posting of UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check that all the php files (controllers and what not) are also UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Use CodeIgniter's Convert To Entities function. It's rather awesome.